# Problem with ether mining, stuck in DAG generation loop

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, ether, clients, dag

i am completely new to ether mining, recently attempted to mine some ether using my desktop.
I came across a comprehensive guide from this link: https://www.cryptocompare.com/mining/guides/how-to-mine-ethereum/ and i followed every step mentioned. Everything was going smoothly. However, after the block got synchronised, i ran the ethminer -G command, DAG generation keep repeating (when it reaches 100%, it restarted from 0% again).
Has anyone encountered problems like this and how do you go about solving it? Appreciate all your help and thanks

Comment: Can you post the output? When you say repeating, I think the DAG for `epoch 1` is being generated, which is usual. Miner keeps the DAG for next epoch ready for easy transition.

Comment: I would guess your blockchain is not synchronized yet. Do check that first.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like your graphics card is running out of memory, I had something similar when my miner was trying to use my onboard graphics card.  You will need a graphics card with more than 4gb minimum to mine.